# Run more than one class programmatically

Tags: testng

I want to run more than one class programmatically.  Can anyone tell me the best way to run more than one class one by one programmmatically?

Comment: What test framework do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
TestNG result = new TestNG();
result.setTestClasses(new Class[] { A.class, A.class });
result.run();
```